# Передать файл через сокет python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, передача-данных, pickle

Я имею следующее

**Client.py**

```
def get_path_file(self):
   try:
       file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, )
       file = open(str(file_path), mode="rb")
       full_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
       
       while True:
           x = file.read(1000)
           print(f"X --- {x}")
           if not x: break
           list_for_server = ["FILE", IDRoom, self.nick_name, self.listWidget_people.currentItem().text(),x, full_name]
           list_for_server = pickle.dumps(list_for_server)
           self.cl.send_data(list_for_server)
   except FileNotFoundError:
       pass
```

**Server.py**

```
while True:  # Accepting a message
   self.signal = socket_user.recv(4096)
   self.signal = pickle.loads(self.signal)
```

Короче говоря, я передаю файл по частям, и сервер принимает его, НО после **второй** итерации я получаю эту ошибку, именно после второй итерации.

```
  File "/home/n76/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/n76/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/n76/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/server.py", line 43, in listen_socket
    self.signal = pickle.loads(self.signal)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ' '.
```

Однако, если я добавлю time.sleep, все отлично работает, и ошибка не возникает

```
def get_path_file(self):
    try:
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, )
        file = open(str(file_path), mode="rb")
        full_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        for IDRoom, nameRoom in self.roomsForLoad[0].items():
            if self.listWidget_people.currentItem().text() == nameRoom:
                while True:
                    time.sleep(0.1)    #<--------- THIS
                    x = file.read(1000)
                    print(f"X --- {x}")
                    if not x: break
                    list_for_server = ["FILE", IDRoom, self.nick_name, self.listWidget_people.currentItem().text(),
                                           x, full_name]

                    list_for_server = pickle.dumps(list_for_server)
                    self.cl.send_data(list_for_server)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
```

Может питон физически не успевает принимать так быстро списки?

Comment: TCP-соединение в сокете — это непрерывный поток байтов. Если вы отправите несколько pickle.dumps подряд — они слепятся в один большой кусок данных. Сервер получит этот слепленный кусок данных и конечно же не сможет его адекватно прочитать, потому что не знает, где заканчивается один кусок и начинается другой. Вам нужно придумать какой-нибудь способ разделения сообщений в потоке (например, перед отправкой pickle.dumps отправлять два или четыре байта с длиной отправляемых данных) и на сервере соответствующим образом образом разделять поток на отдельные сообщения

Comment: Кроме того, вам нужно учитывать, что `recv(4096)` может вернуть абсолютно любое число байт от 0 до 4096 — в том числе может оказаться так, что один pickle.dumps может оказаться разрезан посередине на два отдельных recv'а (или даже больше чем на два). Поэтому вам нужен не только способ разделения сообщений, но и сборка кусочков сообщений в одно цельное сообщение на сервере, прежде чем пихать его в pickle.loads

Comment: @andreymal
Я понимаю о чем вы, но я никак не могу понять как сделать разделитель, есть какие-нибудь примеры, или литература? Я не особо опытен в работе с передаче фалов через сокеты (а точнее опыта вообще нет). Буду очень благодарен если что-нибудь подскажете по этому поводу